# nginx http to https redirect causing 400 Bad Request: the plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, https, security-certificate, nginx

I am running my own webserver with nginx on ubuntu 17.10. I have opened ports 80 and 443.

Trying to get the HTTP to HTTPS redirect working, but everthing i seem to have tried fails. i am still getting the **400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port error** when i navigate directly to the http site.

Hoping someone can spot the issue in my nginx config file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document
    # root concurs with nginx's one

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;

    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        auth_basic off;
        autoindex on;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your server isn't connected via IPv6, and you only needed the standard IPv4 entries:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root  /var/www/html/example.com/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    .....the rest of your port 443 arguments....
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is not the nginx conf, but the sites conf file. Your 301 redirect from http to https seems correct, but you are requiring a secure connection prior to accepting the connection through https, thus triggering a 400 error.

Just comment out the `ssl on;` line like so:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    #ssl on;
    ...
```

or set to off:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl off;
    ...
```

I also recommend you add http2 to the ipv4 block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl off;
    ...
```

More information [here](https://www.tecmint.com/fix-400-bad-request-in-nginx/).